# Check existence of sub-table in a table in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table 't' and a sub-table 'st'.
If the values of subtable matches with that of table then we want to update the 't' table with value Y in new column named 'exists' else N.

```
Table:
q)t:([] id:("ab";"cd";"ef";"gh";"ij"); refid:("";"ab";"";"ef";""); typ:`BUY`SELL`BUY`SELL`BUY)
q)t
id   refid typ
---------------
"ab" ""    BUY
"cd" "ab"  SELL
"ef" ""    BUY
"gh" "ef"  SELL
"ij" ""    BUY

subtable:
q)st:([] id:("ab";"cd"); typ:`BUY`SELL)
q)st
id   typ
---------
"ab" BUY
"cd" SELL

Desired Output:
id   refid typ  exists
----------------------
"ab" ""    BUY  Y
"cd" "ab"  SELL Y
"ef" ""    BUY  N
"gh" "ef"  SELL N
"ij" ""    BUY  N
```

Tried various things like any,each,right each, in - but could get desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `left join (lj)`

```
q) update `N^exists from t lj `id`typ xkey update exists:`Y from st
```

```
id   refid typ  exists
----------------------
"ab" ""    BUY  Y     
"cd" "ab"  SELL Y     
"ef" ""    BUY  N     
"gh" "ef"  SELL N     
"ij" ""    BUY  N
```

Here I have defined `id` and `typ` columns as keys for `st` table. Change the keys of table `st` to the columns you want to match with table `t`.

Answer (score 2):

Rahul's answer is by far neater than what follows, but the following may be more performant, depending on your table sizes. By matching the columns in `t` to `st` (indexing and flipping) and determining a boolean of matching rows, passed into YN boolean dictionary we can produce the desired result.

```
q)`N`Y (flip cols[st]!t[cols[st]]) in st
`Y`Y`N`N`N
q)update exists:(`N`Y (flip cols[st]!t[cols[st]]) in st) from t
id   typ  refid exists
----------------------
"ab" BUY  ""    Y
"cd" SELL "ab"  Y
"ef" BUY  ""    N
"gh" SELL "ef"  N
"ij" BUY  ""    N
q)\t:100000 update exists:(`N`Y (flip cols[st]!t[cols[st]]) in st) from t
446
q)\t:100000 update `N^exists from t lj `id`typ xkey update exists:`Y from st
856
```

Rahuls lj method may generalize to be faster once attributes are applied.

Edited as per Rahuls observations,

Comment: You need to change `c` to cols[st]  else it will give an error because an assignment is not allowed in this section of qsql.  Also, the command could be made shorter as - ` update exists:\`N\`Y (cols[st]#t) in st from t `

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to the other answers is to extract the sub table columns from `t` (`cols[st]#t`)and check they are in `st`:

```
update exists:(cols[st]#t)in st from t
id   refid typ  exists
----------------------
"ab" ""    BUY  1
"cd" "ab"  SELL 1
"ef" ""    BUY  0
"gh" "ef"  SELL 0
"ij" ""    BUY  0
```

If you need to display the result as YN then you can make a slight modification to get the following:

```
update exists:`N`Y(cols[st]#t)in st from t
id   refid typ  exists
----------------------
"ab" ""    BUY  Y
"cd" "ab"  SELL Y
"ef" ""    BUY  N
"gh" "ef"  SELL N
"ij" ""    BUY  N
```